CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID admin. An invalid user ID or password was specified
I get
CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID admin. An invalid user ID or password was specified.

while trying to log into the IBM MQ website console. According to the setup, IBM MQ is running like Docker image successfully (in Stack trace i get - Started web server). I'm able to open in browser (GOOGLE Chrome) the URL of the docker image like https://localhost:8031/ibmmq/console/login.html but if i try to login via credentials like user: admin & password: passw0rd, then i get the error message. The app is biult using Java & Spring Boot. The OS of my computer is Windows 11 Home.
This is the docker-compose.yml relevant part:
version: '3.8'
name: 'ekkv-devkit-localenvironment'

volumes:
  ekkv-volume-pgsql:

networks:
  ekkv-network:
    name: 'ekkv-network'

services:
  ibmmq:
    image: icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq:latest
    container_name: 'ekkv-devkit-ibmmq'
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: "./.docker/ibmmq/20-config.mqsc"
        target: /etc/mqm/20-config.mqsc
        read_only: true
        bind:
          create_host_path: false
    environment:
      - LICENSE=accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1
    ports:
      - "8014:1414"
      - "8031:9443"
    networks:
      - ekkv-network

(*other services (pgsql, mockserver, rabbitmq)

This is the content of ./.docker/ibmmq/20-config.mqsc
ALTER QMGR MAXMSGL(104857600)
ALTER CHANNEL(SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MAXMSGL(104857600)
ALTER CHANNEL(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(clntconn) MAXMSGL(104857600)

DEFINE QLOCAL(Q.PSB.01.EKKV2.REQUEST) MAXMSGL(104857600) REPLACE
DEFINE QLOCAL(Q.PSB.02.EKKV2.REQUEST) MAXMSGL(104857600) REPLACE

This is the content of /etc/mqm/20-config.mqsc
ALTER QMGR MAXMSGL(104857600)
ALTER CHANNEL(SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MAXMSGL(104857600)
ALTER CHANNEL(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(clntconn) MAXMSGL(104857600)

DEFINE QLOCAL(Q.PSB.01.EKKV2.REQUEST) MAXMSGL(104857600) REPLACE
DEFINE QLOCAL(Q.PSB.02.EKKV2.REQUEST) MAXMSGL(104857600) REPLACE

This is the application.yml relevant part:
ibm:
  mq:
    queue-manager: QM1
    channel: DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
    conn-name: localhost(8014)
    user: admin
    password: passw0rd

The relevant docker image info:
ekkv-devkit-ibmmq
icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq:latest
0d8e6a56028f

8014:1414⁠
8031:9443⁠

STATUS: running

This is the end of the stack trace:
2024-04-03T06:33:23.581836867Z 2024-04-03T06:33:23.581Z Started web server
2024-04-03T06:33:28.085684593Z 2024-04-03T06:33:27.954Z CWPKI0803A: SSL certificate created in 6.882 seconds. SSL key file: /mnt/mqm/data/web/installations/Installation1/servers/mqweb/resources/security/key.jks
2024-04-03T06:33:28.085768647Z 2024-04-03T06:33:27.955Z Successfully loaded default keystore: /mnt/mqm/data/web/installations/Installation1/servers/mqweb/resources/security/key.jks of type: JKS
2024-04-03T06:33:28.586619511Z 2024-04-03T06:33:28.172Z CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint-ssl has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv4) port 9443.
2024-04-03T06:33:28.586690985Z 2024-04-03T06:33:28.182Z CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): https://b33634fc62f5:9443/ibmmq/console/
2024-04-03T06:33:28.586703826Z 2024-04-03T06:33:28.193Z CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): https://b33634fc62f5:9443/ibmmq/rest/
2024-04-03T06:33:28.586714622Z 2024-04-03T06:33:28.201Z CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): https://b33634fc62f5:9443/ibmmq/console/internal/
CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID admin. An invalid user ID or password was specified.

The Docker is up to date to the lates version (25.0.3) with OS type Linux. Here is full info:
Client:
 Version:    25.0.3
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.12.1-desktop.4
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-buildx.exe
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.24.6-desktop.1
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-compose.exe
  debug: Get a shell into any image or container. (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  0.0.24
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-debug.exe
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-dev.exe
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.2.22
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-extension.exe
  feedback: Provide feedback, right in your terminal! (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.0.4
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-feedback.exe
  init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.0.1
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-init.exe
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)
    Version:  0.6.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-sbom.exe
  scout: Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.5.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-scout.exe

Server:
 Containers: 4
  Running: 4
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 9
 Server Version: 25.0.3
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: ae07eda36dd25f8a1b98dfbf587313b99c0190bb
 runc version: v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: unconfined
 Kernel Version: 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 16
 Total Memory: 7.463GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: 52f155df-3e5c-429f-bfda-179556b2411a
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5555
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false


I tried different web browsers - Google Chrome, Mozzila and i get same response.

(The response: CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID admin. An invalid user ID or password was specified.)

I tried different credentials like (with same response):

Platform            MQ Version    Credentials
Containers/Docker   Any           Username: admin Password: passw0rd
Linux or Windows    9.0.2 or above    Username: mqadmin Password: mqadmin
Linux or Windows    9.0.1 or below    Username: admin Password: admin


I tried to restart, stopp, start, and even recreate the Docker container multiple times and get the same result.

I double checked the credentials in a case of typo or case sensitivity - didn't solve the issue.

I tried to find out the solution by Googling. Couln't find anything helpfull.

I tried to check the console of the web browser for something helpfull - there is nothing.

I checked the recommended Docker setup (update version, Linux OS) & checked the activity of the relevant Image.

The Docker App is allowed via Windows Firewall.

Network connectivity looks fine since I'm able to access the web service running inside the Docker container via https://localhost:8031/ibmmq/console/login.html without any issues, which indicates that the network connectivity between my host machine and the Docker container is working fine for this particular port (8031 in this case).

I'm trying to solve this by myself and by help of my colleague, but didn't resolve the problem.

Now I ask for a help the mighty internet people - what could be wrong and how to fix it?



The latest builds of the IBM MQ image do not default the admin and app passwords. You will need to specify them.
eg.
    environment:
      - LICENSE=accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1
      - MQ_APP_PASSWORD=${APP_PASSWORD:?err}
      - MQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD:?err}

Where the actually passwords are passed in via .env file, that looks like:
# Uncomment the lines below and set your passwords
# APP_PASSWORD=
# ADMIN_PASSWORD=


i do specify them in application.yml like queue-manager: QM1, user: admin, password: passw0rd as seen in the description of the question

That is for the application to use and connect, and not for the MQ container itself. The MQ container no longer defaults the admin and app passwords, and they need to be specified when the MQ container image is started.

I see, that was quick and helpfull, now i can log in. Thank you!
